# Permission denied using remove function

Tags: c, file

I got this code

```
void deletar_pokemon(){
    FILE* file = fopen("pokemonfinal.txt", "r");
    FILE* temp_file = fopen("temp____file.txt", "w"); //arquivo temporário pra escrever as mudanças no arquivo principal
    
    int contagem = contar_pokemons() - 2, pokemon_deletar = 0;
    int verificacao_barra_n = contagem;

    printf("Digite o id do pokémon a ser removido: ");
    scanf("%d", &pokemon_deletar);

    struct POKEMON p;
    
    while(fscanf(file, "%d %s %c %d %d %d %d %d %d", &p.id, p.nome, &p.elemento, &p.atk, &p.matk, &p.def, &p.mdef, &p.hp, &p.sp) != EOF || contagem == 0){
        if(p.id != pokemon_deletar){
            if(contagem != verificacao_barra_n) fprintf(temp_file, "\n");
            fprintf(temp_file, "%d %s %c %d %d %d %d %d %d\n ", p.id, p.nome, p.elemento, p.atk, p.matk, p.def, p.mdef, p.hp, p.sp);
            contagem--;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    fclose(temp_file);
    remove("pokemonfinal.txt");
    rename("temp____file.txt", "pokemonfinal.txt");
}
```

Basically I get all the pokemons from a file, create a temporary file and put all pokemons except the one I wanna remove, then I close the files, remove the original file and rename the temporary to be the original one.

Im getting error when trying to remove, so I used

```
    if(remove("pokemonfinal.txt") != 0){
        perror("\nError");
    }
```

So I see its Permission Denied error, I tried to use chmod function in c with

```
    if (chmod("./pokemonfinal.txt", 0777) != 0) {
        perror("\nError chmod");
    }
```

but the error with remove didnt change.

How can I solve?

```
if(fclose(file) == EOF) {
        printf("File didnt close\n");
    }
```

I tried checking if the file wasnt closing right but seens to be ok in this part. Also tried to use unlink but didnt solve.

I've checked my permissions in the txt and the .c and are ok, my file has Read-Only permissions but windows dont let you uncheck the file read only.

Comment: Your permissions on the file are irrelevant.  Removing a file is a change to the directory, so you need to have the correct permissions on the directory.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I checked here and already have full control on the directory

Comment: This is on Windows, yes? Can you delete the file manually via the command prompt or Explorer? If not, try to find out [what is preventing deletion](https://superuser.com/questions/117902).

Comment: @jarmod using Remove-Item in powershell I can delete normally the txt. Yes I use windows 10.

Comment: Were you running that Remove-Item as the same Windows user? Also, did you say that the file was actually read-only and you couldn't change that? Do you know why?

Comment: Did you open Windows PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Yes I run the Remove-Item on the vscode console, same as Im running the code. And about the read-only I'm sorry, I said file but i mean directory, the directory that my txt and c are cant be changed [link](https://superuser.com/questions/577659/folder-always-gets-read-only-even-when-i-change-it)

Comment: @jarmod Im really sorry, just noticed that I'm calling another function and the fclose(file) is under the return so the function wasnt closing the file. Thanks for the help bro

Comment: OK, glad it's resolved. Probably worth adding an answer or deleting the question to ensure people don't spend time trying to help now that it's resolved.